# Import page with new number

Tags: oracle-apex

I exported a page let's say number 9999 and want to replace an existing one with it. How can I import it to another number and overwrite the old one ?

I did a search/replace on the export file but it didn't work.

Execution of the statement was unsuccessful. ORA-00001: unique constraint (APEX_180200.WWV_FLOW_PAGE_PLUGS_PK) violated

Comment: just import it with the same page id of the page you want to replace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on:

1. Are the source and target pages inside one application?
2. You need to create once or you are trying to implement some deployment process?

Simplest way is:

1. Delete target page in the editor;
2. Open source page editor;
3. "+" Icon -> Page As Copy
4. Follow instructions

Answer (score 0):

If the page already exists (and you want to replace it with the one you previously exported), **delete** the page from Apex first, then do the import.

Answer (score 0):

I deleted the old page and duplicated the new one with the number I wanted it to have.